# Unable to get Device token

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to get the device token. Prompt popup for notification is coming with Allow and Not allow options. But my device token method is not called when i am using my client account. When I am just using another account my method is called. Is their any problem with apple developer account or another. I am trying but not getting appropriate solution.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")
        let deviceTokenString: String = (deviceToken.description as NSString)
            .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(characterSet)
            .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "") as String
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(deviceTokenString, forKey: "callBackToken")

    }
```

Comment: post some code, what you are using and how you are calling. i don't think there is any issue with changing the accounts. Make sure you are not changing the app identifiers and make sure push notification capability is turned on.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawala I am also enable push notification on capability . But not working

Comment: Is receive notification enabled on your client device? Maybe he tap "Not allow" on popup when he open app for first time, or change this setting in phone settings.

Comment: no i am also testing . But not getting device token